# nvd3 line chart, how to remove gridlines and yaxis

Tags: charts, line, nvd3.js, gridlines

I have made a line chart with view finder.

Here is my initial code

```
     var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

 // chart.transitionDuration(500);
  chart.xAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',g'));
  chart.xAxis
        .axisLabel("Date");
  chart.xAxis.tickPadding(0);


  chart.x2Axis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',g'));




  chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2g'));
  chart.y2Axis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2h'));
 // chart.showYAxis(false);
```

I want to remove the y axis labels ( i.e. i want no number showing on the y axis).

I also want to remove all the gridlines.

is there something like chart.yAxis.somethinghere to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

> > To remove tick on y-axis

```
.nv-axis.nv-y .tick line {
        display:none;
    }
```

> > To remove tick on x axis

```
.nv-axis.nv-x .tick line {
        display:none;
    }
```

> > To remove label on x axis

```
.showXAxis(false)
```

> > To remove label on y axis

```
.showYAxis(false)
```

> > To remove all the grid lines

```
.nv-axis .tick line {
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: @user3171919 I think you should mark it as an correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

`.showYAxis(false)` should remove the y axis.

If that doesn't work, you can apply `.nv-y text{display: none;}` as a style.

Use the style `.tick line {display: none;}` to get rid of grid lines, and keep x axis.

Get rid of all axis and lines with `.tick{display: none;}`

:)

Comment: If you want to retain the y-axis label, but not display the values: `.nv-axisMaxMin {
 display: none;
}`

Answer (score 3):

To remove the gridlines:

```
    .nv-axis .tick line {
        display:none;
    }
```

And axes can be done more straightforwardly:

```
.showYAxis(false)
.showXAxis(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

To hide grid line, just add this to your css

```
.tick line {
display: none;
}
```

and for the X Axis just add `.showYAxis(false)`

if you want to delete only the yAxis line and keep the ticks you can do it with the CSS:

```
.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-y path.domain{
 stroke-opacity: 0;
}
```

see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oV4cit?p=preview) for example.