# How to hide the y-axis and remove ticks from x-axis in angular nvd3

Tags: angularjs, charts, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am using the existing example from angular nvd3 and try to hide the y-axis and remove the ticks from x-axis.So, I have gone through the document and added showYAxis="false" and added ticks:  null in x-axis object. But, I am not able to hide the y-axis as well as remove the ticks from x-axis. Kindly, find the below link and let me know my mistake.
For y -axis:

```
 <nvd3 options="options" data="data" showYAxis="false"></nvd3>
```

For hiding x-axis ticks

```
 xAxis: {
    axisLabel: 'X Axis',
    ticks: null
  },
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6t5bky?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove Y-axis using css styles.

```
.nv-y text {
  display: none;
}
```

You can remove the grid lines as,

```
.tick {
  display: none;
}
```

**Update:**

You can remove the class `text` in the above style to see the effect.

```
.nv-y {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to display names on the X-Axis for each bar and without grid lines then add `line` class in the above style as,

```
.tick line {
      display: none;
    }
```

Reference: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22404973/967638)

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XAdsQq?p=preview)

**P.S:** I have used nvd3 charts but never tried to hide any axis or grid lines. Chart seems to be good without grid lines .. :)

Comment: But, still y-axis line is visible know. I dont what that line too

Answer (score 2):

it's really easy to get that fixed using the charts options that's already exist on angular NVD3.
to get the y-axis just add `showYAxis: false,` and to hide x-axis ticks just add

```
tickFormat: function(d) {
      return null
    },
```

into your `xAxis` options.
here is a forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqt7b0?p=preview) with the options that you are looking for ;)