# nvd3 - Hide xAxis and display gridview independently

Tags: charts, grid, nvd3.js, candlestick-chart

I have created a Candlestick chart with nvd3 and I would like to hide the values displayed on the xAxis, but not the gridlines. With the use of `.showXAxis(false)`, the xAxis is hidden alongside with the gridlines. 
Is there a way to hide only the values of the xAxis and show the grid? (wanted result is shown in picture below)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nvd3 line chart, how to remove gridlines and yaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055289/nvd3-line-chart-how-to-remove-gridlines-and-yaxis)

Comment: ^ the title tells exactly the opposite, while it might answer your question.

Comment: @MartinZeitler the question you mention hides the x-axis and gridlines. I have used this code, though when I hide the x-axis, the gridlines is hidden also. I want to hide only the x-axis but ddisplay the gridlines, this is my question

Comment: guess you would have to set the grid-lines to `display: block` or even `display: block !important` to enforce it... CSS can also be applied with JS, eg. on whatever chart-event, which is being triggered.